# custom axes layout using axis_grid toolkit

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have an issue with `make_axes_locatable/append_axes` in the axis_grid toolkit, when the function calls are nested, e.g.,

```
divider1 = make_axes_locatable(ax1)
divider2 = make_axes_locatable(divider1.append_axes(...))
```

If I use the above code to create 3 axes like in  [(4,5,6)](http://matplotlib.org/_images/demo_gridspec03.png), the main axis (ax4) is hidden behind the other two on the right (see figure below and [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thisch/d8e0f3f3cf1b9be241e5)). I guess `make_axes_locatable/append_axes` is not meant to be used this way.

[image]

All I want is to place the colorbar not at the top of ax1 (like in the figure below -  [this gist](https://gist.github.com/thisch/3e02d3642dc0bbddfc08)) but in the empty space below the table. The advantage of `make_axes_locatable` is that the figure still looks good if I resize it, in contrast to manually creating axis objects using `fig.add_axes()` (code at the end of [4](https://gist.github.com/thisch/3e02d3642dc0bbddfc08)).

**Can anyone tell me how to split the right axis (ax2) s.t. all space below the table is used for the colorbar and its ticklabels?**

[image: blabla]

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure you can do this with only `AxesDivider.append_axes` since according to the [documentation](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/api/axes_divider_api.html) that method "create[s] an axes at the given position with the same height (or width) of the main axes." You want axes on the right that have different heights than the one on the left.

Another option is to create two subplots and use a divider to break up the subplots on the right:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid1 import make_axes_locatable

ax = plt.subplot(121)
ax2 = plt.subplot(122)
divider = make_axes_locatable(ax2)
ax3  = divider.append_axes("bottom", size="50%", pad=0.5)

plt.show()
```

Or create a `Divider` directly (without using `makes_axes_locatable`) as shown [here](http://matplotlib.org/mpl_toolkits/axes_grid/users/axes_divider.html) and below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.axes_grid import Divider
import mpl_toolkits.axes_grid.axes_size as Size

fig1 = plt.figure(1, (5.5, 4.))

# the rect parameter will be ignore as we will set axes_locator
rect = (0.1, 0.1, 0.8, 0.8)
ax = [fig1.add_axes(rect, label="%d"%i) for i in range(3)]

horiz = [Size.Scaled(1.5), Size.Fixed(.5), Size.Scaled(1.),
         Size.Scaled(.5)]

vert = [Size.Scaled(1.), Size.Fixed(.5), Size.Scaled(1.5)]

# divide the axes rectangle into grid whose size is specified by horiz * vert
divider = Divider(fig1, rect, horiz, vert, aspect=False)
ax[0].set_axes_locator(divider.new_locator(nx=0, ny=0, ny1=3))
ax[1].set_axes_locator(divider.new_locator(nx=2, ny=2))
ax[2].set_axes_locator(divider.new_locator(nx=2, ny=0))

plt.show()
```

Or if there is no reason to use a `Divider` at all, you could use [GridSpec](http://matplotlib.org/users/gridspec.html):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0,0), rowspan=2)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (0, 1))
ax3 = plt.subplot2grid((2,2), (1, 1))

plt.show()
```

All three of those options will create something that looks about this:

[image: three axes in a figure]

All three of these looked ok when I resized them, at least with this simple example.

**EDIT**
You can use `gridspec` and `Subplot`to get an axes on the left with an aspect ratio of one and a pair of axes on the right that line up with the top and bottom of the left axes. The trick is to set the aspect ration of the `gridspec` using `width_ratios` and `height_ratios`. When this figure  is resized the top and bottom of the right axes will still line up with the top and bottom of the left axes.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec

fig = plt.figure()

# grid spec for left and right columns
gs0 = gridspec.GridSpec(1, 2,width_ratios=[1,1], height_ratios=[1,1])

# gird spec for left axes with aspect ratio of 1
gs00 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(1, 1, subplot_spec=gs0[0], width_ratios=[1], height_ratios=[1])
ax1 = plt.Subplot(fig, gs00[0])
fig.add_subplot(ax1)

# grid spec for two right axes
gs01 = gridspec.GridSpecFromSubplotSpec(2, 1, subplot_spec=gs0[1])
ax2 = plt.Subplot(fig, gs01[0])
ax3 = plt.Subplot(fig, gs01[1])
fig.add_subplot(ax2)
fig.add_subplot(ax3)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: I probably should have mentioned it explicitly - the aspect ratio of ax1 in my examples is set to 1. Therefore I used make_axis_locatable(ax1) to split ax1 horizontally (because the resizing behavior is better). Compare resizing the plot in your examples given that ax1.set_aspect(1) is set to my example https://gist.github.com/thisch/3e02d3642dc0bbddfc08

Comment: I'm guessing that you mean the resize behavior is "better" in that the top and bottom of the left and right axes are always aligned. I've edited my answer to include an example that accomplishes this.